# XCode 12.5.1 simulator is not seen under /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes

Tags: xcode, xcode-simulator

After upgrading XCode to latest version `12.5.1` , checked folder

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes
```

this doesn't show any simulator even when XCode is showing default simulators installed with latest version of iOS

Answer (score 0):

The default simulator runtimes are shipping inside of Xcode.app.  Xcode will install additional runtimes to /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Runtimes.

Comment: can you please specify path to check default simulator ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apple Developer article [Installing and managing Simulator runtimes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes#) for Xcode 14:

> Manage the amount of storage that Xcode requires by choosing *Xcode > Preferences > Platforms* to view the **currently installed Simulator runtimes**, and removing any that you don’t need.

<sup>Emphasis and italics mine</sup>

Here's the aforementioned Platforms page in Xcode 14's Preferences:

[image: Screenshot taken on macOS Ventura of Xcode 14 preferences in the Platforms tab]

On Xcode 12 and 13, it is located in *Xcode > Preferences > Components*:

[image: Screenshot of Xcode 12 and 13 preferences in the Components tab (showing the currently installed simulator runtimes) from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68966581]

You can do this easily in the Xcode preferences, no need to use Finder.